# Assign first value in the day to the rest of the rows for that day using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Please, I have a pandas dataframe containing intraday data for 2 stocks.
The index is a time series sampled by minute (i.e. 1/1/2017 9:30, 1/1/2017 9:31, 1/1/2017 9:32, ...).
There are only two columns "Price A", "Price B".
Total number of rows = 52000.
I need to create a new column in which I store the 9.30 am value for every day.
Assuming for 1/1/2017, the 9:30 am "Price A" is 150, I would need to store this value in a new column called "Open A" for every row that has the same day.
For example:[image]

Sample input:

```
                     Price A  Price B
date                                 
2017-01-01 09:30:00      150        1
2017-01-01 09:31:00      153        2
2017-01-01 09:31:00      149        3
2017-01-01 09:31:00      151        4
2017-02-01 09:30:00      145        1
2017-02-01 09:31:00      139        2
2017-02-01 09:31:00      142        3
2017-02-01 09:31:00      149        4
```

I tried to simply use:

for ind in df.index:
    df['Open A'][ind] = 2

just to make a test but this seems to be taking forever.
I also tried to read what's available here:
[How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas) 
but it doesn't seem to be of help.
does anybody have a suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I follow. But, you may want a `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1D'))['Price A'].transform('first')`

Comment: Do you mind converting this picture into some text that I can copy and run in a terminal to whip up an answer for you? It would help everyone.

Comment: Is your index in the DataFrame actually accurate? The data you show there seem to have years of `17` and `217`... (not to mention it doesn't appear to actually be sampled (duplicate minutes occurring)) - if that's the source data  (in Excel maybe) - you  really should post your actual DataFrame and a reproducible sample in a code block and not as an image...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - hi guys, my honest and serious apologizes, it's my intention to learn how to clearly upload my data. To answer your question, I do have a perfectly sampled data with frequency at minute level and 9:30 is indeed the first value (row) for each day. May I ask the logic of .transform?

Comment: How it works is, it computes the output for each group, and then replicates each value so that the result is the same length as the original dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If needed, set your index to `datetime` -

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, errors='coerce')
```

---

```
df

                     Price A  Price B
date                                 
2017-01-01 09:30:00      150        1
2017-01-01 09:31:00      153        2
2017-01-01 09:31:00      149        3
2017-01-01 09:31:00      151        4
2017-02-01 09:30:00      145        1
2017-02-01 09:31:00      139        2
2017-02-01 09:31:00      142        3
2017-02-01 09:31:00      149        4
```

An assumption here is that your day's recordings start at `9:30`, making our job really easy.

Use `groupby` with a `pd.Grouper` + `transform` + `first` -

```
df['Open A'] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1D'))['Price A'].transform('first')    
df

                     Price A  Price B  Open A
date                                         
2017-01-01 09:30:00      150        1     150
2017-01-01 09:31:00      153        2     150
2017-01-01 09:31:00      149        3     150
2017-01-01 09:31:00      151        4     150
2017-02-01 09:30:00      145        1     145
2017-02-01 09:31:00      139        2     145
2017-02-01 09:31:00      142        3     145
2017-02-01 09:31:00      149        4     145
```

Comment: thank you all so much for all the help so far. Please, could anybody point me to where I can learn how to upload the code and current pandas dataframe I have here? I feel bad for having uploaded a not useful picture. thanks again, Andrea

Comment: @Coldspeed thank you so much, your answer is perfect. only thing, " paste the output into your question.".  I tried but the output was a mess, not formatted. I thought there was a different way to do it.

Comment: @Andrea Once pasted, highlight the data and hit ctrl+K. It's all mentioned in the Tour.